# TX/RX 16 bits data SPI in MSP432 from TI

Tags: spi, msp430, msp432

[image]

[image]

Hello, I am trying to communicate with the AS5048A encoder that requires a 16-bit SPI communication, but I am trying to establish communication with a MSP432 microcontroller and its SPI TX/RX buffers are 8 bits (because the MSB byte is reserved) and I can't establish the communication. I would like to know if someone can see what the error is or if it is the right way to do it.

```
uint8_t SPI_Transfer(uint8_t byte) {

    // Wait for transmit buffer to be empty
    while (!(EUSCI_A3->IFG & EUSCI_A_IFG_TXIFG));

    // Write data to transmit buffer
    EUSCI_A3->TXBUF = byte;

    // Wait for receive buffer to be full
    while (!(EUSCI_A3->IFG & EUSCI_A_IFG_RXIFG));

    // Read data from receive buffer
    return EUSCI_A3->RXBUF;
}

uint16_t AS5048A_ReadAngle(void) {

    uint16_t angulo = 0;

    uint8_t comando[2] = {0xFF, 0xFF};

    // Select AS5048A
    P9->OUT &= ~BIT4;


    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        angle[i] = SPI_Transfer(comando[i]);  // Send read command

    }

    // Send dummy byte to receive angle
    // angulo = SPI_Transfer(0x0000);

    // Deselect AS5048A
    P9->OUT |= BIT4;

    angulo = ((angle[0] << 8) | (angle[1])); //conversion to uint16t
    angulo =  angulo & 0x3FFF; // to eliminate two first bits that don't represent data (err and parity)

    return angulo;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not transmit/receive twice from the MSP for every one receive/transmit on the AS5048A? You can use a global 8-byte buffer and toggle (something like `uint8_t first_byte[8];` and `volatile bool second_byte;`) and in in your SPI interrupt on the MSP `if (!second_byte) { /* save first_byte */; second_byte = true; } else { /* transmit first_byte, transmit current byte */; second byte = false; }` There is also a FIFO you can use if I recall correctly. I'd investigate something similar as my first thought.

Comment: I guess that's not the problem actually. I was basically wondering what should I do if the SPI buffers of the MCU are 16 bits long, but the first 8 bits are reserved and the encoder is waiting for 16bits to understand the frame.

Comment: I don't actually think that is a problem. You will configure MISO and MOSI to establish the master/slave SPI communication. Since they will each send a byte at a time and either a `0x00` or `0xFF` as an acknowledgment between the bytes received, you should be able to use the same toggle approach above to send or receive 2-bytes by the AS5048A just by checking the acknowledgement in between and using the bytes on either side for the 16-bit buffer on one side and vice versa. Have a look at [MSP430 SPI](https://www.argenox.com/library/msp430/msp430-spi-peripheral-chapter-9/)